# Show search when scroll down RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have activity with `RecyclerView` and `Toolbar`. I want do that when user scrolls down `RecyclerView` between `ToolBar` and `RecyclerView` showing Search(edit text). When user scrolls up `RecyclerView` - Search(edit text) hiding. How I can realize that?